# Some keyboard keys not working on password input to Yosemite login screen

Tags: keyboard, macos, password

As stated in the title some keys don't work when trying to input my password into the Yosemite login screen. The weird thing is that if my mouse isn't plugged in (Razer Naga) when I turn on my Macbook Pro the issue doesn't occur and if I restart my Macbook Pro, even with the mouse plugged in, then everything works as expected. Anytime the Mac is restarted in the keyboard works as expected on the login screen but when powering the Mac on it doesn't.

I have done an SMC reset to no avail. I never had this problem in any previous versions of OS X.

UPDATE:
I started plugging my Razer mouse into a monitor stand with a built-in USB hub and now the problem almost never happens... it still does occur, but probably only 10-20% of the time as opposed to 100% when the mouse was plugged in directly to the Macbook on startup.

Comment: I've had this happen and needed to power down the Mac and reset the SMC. Could you edit the post to let us know if the these isolation steps were done and if the issue persists across reboots?

Comment: Thanks for the help, @bmike! I did the SMC reset and the problem still occurs after waking my Mac from a system shutdown. However, anytime I restart the Mac it the keyboard works fine on the login screen.

Comment: Try a pRAM reset. Clear the sinuses and all.

Comment: I did the pRAM reset with no luck. Thanks for the help though @JakeStewart

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the keyboard works at the boot screen before user level code runs is curious.

I wonder if one of the kernel extensions or control panels that customize that keyboard are causing issues. As I don't have that hardware, it's hard to poke and see what files might be causing the issue.

You can try several things to corner this:

1. Make a new user account and turn off auto log in in the Users preference pane
2. You could hold shift down when booting to rebuild all kernel extensions and then log in safely without most third party apps running
3. You could uninstall any drivers and/or open a support ticket with the vendor

In each of the above cases, you can test logging in to the new account / safe boot system and see which are broken and which are working. Worst case, edit the question and/or open a new question with the details of this triage.

Comment: I don't think it'd be the keyboard but instead maybe the Razer mouse or the Razer Synapse program that controls it? Maybe not Synapse because it shouldn't be launched quite yet since it launches on startup. I'll try giving the things you've mentioned a try and update the question.

Comment: I tried your first 2 suggestions with no luck. I do already know though that the problem doesn't exist with my Razer Naga mouse not plugged in so it's either the Razer Driver or possibly Razer's Synapse program causing the problem. But I assumed that since it was working in Mavericks just fine that this was probably an issue with Yosemite. That might not be the case so I'm going to submit a bug report to Razer and see if I get anywhere.